# User directing to login page after the user has already login - Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-7

I am trying to learn laravel and I'm stuck at this problem in redirecting the normal user to the dashboard. The process that I did was the same with the admin account -- which is working -- but with the normal user it always redirects the login account but the user is already login. It also doesn't redirect with the middleware. I'm not sure where or what is wrong and the problem is like this [image problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1S8t.png)

**My LoginController.php looks like this:**

```
protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
        protected function redirectTo(){
            if(Auth()->user()->roles == 'admin'){
                return route('admin.dashboard');
            }
            if (Auth()->user()->roles == 'user') {
                return route('user.dashboard');
            };
        }
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'=>'required|email',
        'password'=>'required',
    ]);

    if (Auth()->attempt(array('email'=>$input['email'], 'password'=>$input['password']))) {
        if (Auth()->user()->roles = 'admin') {
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
        }
        elseif (Auth()->user()->roles = 'user') {
            return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
        }
    }
    else{
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('error','Emails and password are incorrect');
    }
}
```

**My web.php:**

```
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'user','middleware'=>['isUser','auth','PreventBackHistory']], function(){
    Route::get('/dashboard', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'index'])->name('user.dashboard');
    Route::get('/settings', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'settings'])->name('user.settings');
});
```

**My User Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('dashboards.cs.user.cs_index');
    }
    public function settings()
    {
        return view('dashboards.cs.user.cs_settings');
    }
}
```

**UserMiddleware.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class isUserMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->roles == 'user'){
            return $next($request);
        }
        else{
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure where the process is wrong. I hope someone could explain it. Thank you.

Comment: In the middlewares, can you change the order of the middlewares from 
    `['isUser','auth','PreventBackHistory']` to `['auth', 'isUser','PreventBackHistory']` and see how it goes

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din The problem still there,  I've also tried to purposely write some stuff and delete some codes to have errors in web.php,  middleware, and the UserController but it still login the user and the errors aren't appearing

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din The problem is fix, I needed to add session_domain on the .env file. Thank you.